# Objects Disappear as Soon as Distribute On Faces Node is Added

Tags: objects, geometry-nodes

I have a plane which I want to manipulate in geometry nodes. As soon as I add **Distribute On Faces** node, it disappears/become invisible, I can only see the outlines.

I tried adding **Join Geometry** node, it did not help. **Now when I render it, the objects are seen.**

Any Ideas?

Now when I render it, the objects are visible.

[image: invisible objects]

[image: render objects are visible]

---

Thank you, the first solution might work with the tutorial.

But do you have any idea how he achieved the following only with Disturbed Points on Faces ?

[image: object]

This is the exact point in the tutorial - https://youtu.be/oA4maNXlIf0?t=108

Comment: Could you add some screenshots, it would be helpful

Answer (score 3):

There is no "Distribute on Faces" Node, there is  "Distribute points on Faces". It distributes points, that's not visible. You should use instance on points to scatter some instances on distributed points. As an instance, you can use object from scene or mesh primitive like this:

[image]

Then you can use Join Geometry to join instanced points and original geometry together:

[image]

> But do you have any idea how he achieved the following only with Disturbed Points on Faces ?

You have material shading enabled:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**THE SOLUTION:**

I tried to view it in "material preview mode", but the material is not there.
**They are visible in "Solid Mode".**